# Spark Cluster: How to print out the content of RDD on each worker node

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I just started learning apache spark and wanted to know why this is not working for me.

I am running spark 2.1 and started a master and a worker (not local). This my code:

```
object SimpleApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val file = [FILELOCATION]
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val textFile = sc.textFile(file)   
    val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                         .map(word => (word.toLowerCase.toCharArray.toList.sorted.mkString, 1))
                         .reduceByKey(_ + _)

    counts.map(println)
    counts.foreach(println)

    val countCollect = counts.collect()

    sc.stop()    
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to get the worker nodes to print out their contents in stdout. Even if I set the master and worker to local, it does not seem to work.

Am I understanding something wrong here?

Comment: How are you running the job? through IDE or `spark-submit`?

Comment: I am running it through spark-submit

Comment: have you checked executor's logs?

Comment: Could you try using ```countCollect.map(println)```? Let me know if this works.

Comment: I have tried this and nothing has been printed on the worker's shell

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print something in executor a normal println will do. That will print the output in the executor's stdout

Comment: I am able to collect back the rdd and print the collected content through [counts.collect().foreach(println)] but I'm assuming that is on the driver's side. The problem I'm having is to print the distributed content of the rdd on the executor's side. I want to be able to see how the document has been split up among the worker nodes and see the process in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can Actually view the worker status, Application status stderr, stdout of each workers rdd distribution and many more things in viewing in **localhost:8080** in the browser [Master Machine]. click on worker-Id you can view logs (stdout,stderr). If you want to see the actual distribution and status you can click on running application, In that click on **Application Detailed UI** link it will show complete details of your application.

If you want to view worker UI only then you can see by typing **localhost:8081** in worker system.

Comment: I went into localhost:8080 and tried to see what was printed on stdout, but it was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you submit a Spark Job, the tasks (instructions) for the Spark job go from the driver to the executors. The driver can be running on the same node that you are currently logged onto (local and YARN-client) or the driver can be on another node (Application master).

All the actions return back a result to the driver, so if you are logged onto to the machine where the driver runs, you can see the output. But you cannot see the output on the executor nodes since any print statement will be printed on the console of respective machines. You can just do a sc.textFile() and it will save all the partitions into the directory separately. In this way you can see the contents in each partition.